# Use mutex to control timing of while loop

Tags: c, while-loop, pthreads, iteration, mutex

I would like to understand how to use threads to control the execution of an instruction within a loop. I cannot use sleep in the main function for this purpose, as that would block the main thread for some time. Instead, I just want to ensure that the next iteration of the while loop is not reached if a certain time hasn't elapsed yet. Currently, I have another thread that just enables a flag called `go_on`.

It works, but, is there a way to do this with mutex?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void *thread_proc(void *arg)
{
    int *go_on = (int *)arg;
    while(1)
    {
        sleep(1);
        *(go_on) = 1;
    }
}

int main()
{
    int go_on = 0;

    pthread_t tid;
    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, &thread_proc, (void *)&go_on);

    int counter = 0;    
    while(1)
    {
        while(go_on == 0){};
        go_on = 0;
        counter += 1;
        printf("%d\n", counter);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you know what mutex is and how to use it?

Comment: Can't u just use gettimeofday if you don't want to sleep your main thread?

Comment: Another approach may be another thread (that contains the code in the main), which is synchronised with `thread_proc` through a semaphore

Comment: @EugeneSh. I understand the concept, but I do not know how to use it

Comment: Simplest thing would be to "guard" your existing flag with the mutex. You must do it anyway, as you might have some race condition.

Comment: @HongyuWang, thank you. I did consider this, I would just like to know if it is possible to do this with threads instead.

Comment: @Jose, thank you, I did not consider this idea. Could you please expand on it?

Comment: @EugeneSh., thank you very much. How does guarding work here?

Comment: Meaning that the thread which is accessing the flag (for read or write) should first aquire the mutex, and release after the operation.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Perfect, I think I understand. Thank you very much.

Comment: A mutex is the wrong type of synchro.  Use a condvar or semaphore.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Based on MasterRem's answer, you can do the following if you want to time an action, and use a `while` loop to do this repeatedly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

pthread_cond_t cv = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void *thread2(void *arg)
{
    while(1) {
        sleep(1);
        //Send signal
        pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
    }
}

int main()
{
    //Create thread2
    pthread_t threadId;
    pthread_create(&threadId, NULL, &thread2, NULL);

    //Lock the mutex
    pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    int counter = 0;

    while(1) {
        //Block the thread on a condition with the locked mutex
        pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &lock);
        counter += 1;
        printf("%d\n", counter);
    }

    //Unlock the mutex
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use signals to communicate between threads.

You block the first thread with a condition and a mutex locked by the calling thread. Then a second thread send a signal to unblock the thread blocked by the condition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

pthread_cond_t cv;
pthread_mutex_t lock;

void *thread2(void *arg)
{
    //Send signal
    pthread_cond_signal(&cv);
}

int main()
{
    //Create thread2
    pthread_t threadId;
    pthread_create(&threadId, NULL, &thread2, NULL);

    //Lock the mutex
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    //Block the thread on a condition with the locked mutex
    pthread_cond_wait(&cv, &lock);

    printf("The thread is now unblocked");

    //Unlock the mutex
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

    return 0;
}
```